# kendoeditor toggle fullscreen working for one id not for multiple ids why

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-editor

working for one id not for two

```
 var kendoEditorFields = '@ApplicationGlobals.SELECTED_COMPANY_CODE' != '@CompanyCode.RICHMOND' ?
 "#txArNcrLineDispositionsDisposition,#txArNcrLineDispositionsCorrectiveAction" : "#txArNcrLineDispositionsDisposition";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var kendoEditorFields = '@ApplicationGlobals.SELECTED_COMPANY_CODE' != '@CompanyCode.RICHMOND' ?
            "#txArNcrLineDispositionsCorrectiveAction,#txArNcrLineDispositionsDisposition" : "#txArNcrLineDispositionsDisposition";

        $(kendoEditorFields).kendoEditor({
            encoded: false,
            paste: function (e) {
                if ((/^<img src="data:image/i).test(e.html)) {
                    e.html = "";
                }
            },
            imageBrowser: {
                transport: {
                    read: "ImageBrowser/Read",
                    destroy: { url: "ImageBrowser/Destroy", type: "POST" },
                    uploadUrl: "ImageBrowser/Upload",
                    thumbnailUrl: "ImageBrowser/Thumbnail",
                    imageUrl: baseUrl + $.cookie("IMAGEBROWSERFILEPATH") + "/{0}"
                }
            },
            tools: [
                "bold",
                "italic",
                "underline",
                "strikethrough",
                "justifyLeft",
                "justifyCenter",
                "justifyRight",
                "justifyFull",
                "insertUnorderedList",
                "insertOrderedList",
                "indent",
                "outdent",
                "createLink",
                "unlink",
                "insertImage",
                "insertFile",
                "subscript",
                "superscript",
                "tableWizard",
                "createTable",
                "addRowAbove",
                "addRowBelow",
                "addColumnLeft",
                "addColumnRight",
                "deleteRow",
                "deleteColumn",
                "viewHtml",
                "formatting",
                "cleanFormatting",
                "fontName",
                "fontSize",
                "foreColor",
                "backColor",
                "print",
                {
                    name: "fullscreen",
                    template: '<a class="toggle-button" onclick="toggleFullScreen()" title="@ResourceStrings.Text_Toggle_Screen"> <span class="k-icon k-i-maximize k-tool-icon" /></a>'
                }
            ]
        });
```